# Get higher-level element with CUBEMEMBER in Excel Powerpivot

Tags: excel, mdx, powerpivot

I have a Chart of Accounts, loaded in PowerPivot based on a SQL query on a database table; the connection is named "ThisWorkbookDataModel" and the table in PowerPivot is named [Accounts].

The Chart of Accounts is structured as follows:

- Group -> Category -> Code -> Description.

For instance:

- Group: Revenue
- Category: Residential
- Account code: 1001
- Account Description: Contract

I would like to be able to extract the Group, Category and Description by simply specifying the Code **dynamically**.

For instance, assuming that cell D1 records Account Code 1001, the formula:

```
CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Accounts].[Account Code].&["&D1&"]")
```

would return "1001". This is fine and well, but I cannot go "up the line" and derive Account Description, Category and Group from Account Code.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the 4 fields into a hierarchy in the Power Pivot add-in window as described [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2900/creating-hierarchies-in-powerpivot-for-excel/).

Then you can easily navigate up the hierarchy with `.Parent` like this:

```
CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Accounts].[Hierarchy Name].[Account Code].&["&D1&"].Parent")
```

Note that you should replace Hierarchy Name with the name of your new hierarchy.

Comment: @Bujor, if any of the provided answers solved your issue you can [mark it as the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to positively close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Hierarchy on Accounts table (that Greg pointed out):

- to extract the Account Denomination (based on Account Code):

**CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Accounts].[GLAccount].[Account Code].&["&$D1&"].Parent")**

- to extract the Account Category (based on Account Description):

**CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Accounts].[GLAccount].[Account Description].&["&$E1&"].Parent")**

- to extract the Account Group (based on Account Category):

**CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Accounts].[GLAccount].[Category].&["&$C1&"].Parent")**

where:

- GLAccount is the name of Hierarchy;
- cell D1 hosts Account Code
- cell E1 hosts Account Description;
- cell C1 hosts Account Category

Nice and easy. Many thanks!